# Counting outs? Any websites provide this?

Tags: nlhe, odds

I often look at a hand plus community cards and fail to see the number of outs mentioned.

A number of sites, such as https://www.cardplayer.com/poker-tools/odds-calculator/texas-holdem offer odds, but I can't find one that will list the outs given a hand and flop for NLHE.

Does anyone know of one (or has written code for one), please?

Comment: This depends on what "outs" you are looking for.  In some cases a pair can be an out, in others making 4 of a kind is the only way you'll win.  First you need to determine what sort of hand you think you need make to win.  Only then can you determine the different ways to make that hand.

Comment: This is also a good video explaining the odds and outs: https://www.pokervip.com/en/coaching-videos/odds-outs

Answer (score 2):

Here is a chart that will show you the outs in certain hand/board combinations and also includes things such as the percentages by turn/river (you can work out rough percentages by using the 4 and 2 rule once your know your outs).

[Link Updated]
https://www.pokervip.com/en/strategy-articles/texas-hold-em-no-limit-beginner/odds-outs-1

Comment: But again, all based on the 'right' count of outs? IMHO it's too easy to make an error! Best I've found to date is http://www.pokerology.com/lessons/drawing-odds/

Comment: I'm afraid I don't follow what you mean by "right count of outs". As long as you know what your drawing too and what hand you currently hold counting outs is fairly easy. The only complicated part is when you compare dirty outs to your opponents likely holdings. Which the above article explains.

Comment: You may find it easy. I don't. E.g. Some seems to subtract discounted outs, others don't.

Comment: The link shows 404 error page.

Comment: Link is still broken or broken again.

Answer (score 1):

If you have trouble with outs, that means you have a low level of understanding, that's OK. The best way for you to learn this might be to just lay out hands and all the remaining card. Just play with everything face up and pick the outs. Being a little more visual on it may change your perspective.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another link, similar to the one posted by David, but always worth reading in a couple of places to improve likelihood of accuracy.

https://www.cardschat.com/odds-for-dummies.php